# docker private registry - basic auth

Tags: docker-registry

I setup an insecure private registry using:

```
[root@docker-regi ~]#docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn myuser mypassword > /auth/htpasswd

[root@docker-regi ~]#docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry_auth  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd"  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm"  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd"  registry:2
```

But when trying to login:

```
[root@docker-remote ~]# !748
docker login -u myuser -p mypassword 192.168.122.190:5000
Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://192.168.122.190:5000/v2/ failed with status: 400 Bad Request
[root@docker-remote ~]#
```

Referred to https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#native-basic-auth && https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first command you wrote out the htpasswd to:

```
/auth/
```

then you mounted:

```
`pwd`/auth
```

**So those directories don't match, you never actually mounted the htpassswd file**

If you write out to `auth/htpasswd` it will work since it's writing to your current directory, not to `/`

The following worked perfectly for me:

```
mkdir auth

docker run --entrypoint htpasswd registry:2 -Bbn myuser mypassword > auth/htpasswd

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry_auth  -v `pwd`/auth:/auth  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH=htpasswd"  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM=Registry Realm"  -e "REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH=/auth/htpasswd"  registry:2

docker login -u myuser -p mypassword localhost:5000
```

Returns:

```
Login Succeeded
```